# Custom DateTime coverter is returning null?

Tags: c#, datetime, csvhelper

I have a model that has a DateTime type property. From this property, I want to include the seconds and microseconds to the string when writing to CSV file and when reading from the CSV file through CsvHelper.

So here is how I came up with the solution by extending the **DefaultTypeConverter**

```
public class CsvDateTimeConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    private const string DateStringFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

    public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return null;

        return Convert.ToDateTime(text);
    }

    public override string ConvertToString(TypeConverterOptions options, object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return "";

        var dateTime = (DateTime) value;

        return dateTime.ToString(DateStringFormat);
    }
}
```

the model looks like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    // ..... removed other properties
    public DateTime MyDateTime {get; set};
}
```

And the CsvClassMapper looks like this

```
public sealed class CsvMap : CsvClassMap<MyModel>
{
    public CsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.MyDateTime).TypeConverter<CsvDateTimeConverter>();
    }
}
```

I registered the class map to the reader and writer. But the problem is:

I can successfully write to the CSV file using the converter but when I try to read from CSV file, it can read the other properties but returns null for the DateTime property.

So.. what am I missing?

**EDITED:**

if it helps:

this is the code to read from csv file:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
     var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
     csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();

     csv.Configuration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

     return csv.GetRecords<MyModel>().ToList();
 }
```

Comment: Replace Convert.ToDateTime(text) with DateTime.ParseExact() and use the format :  "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"

Comment: What custom DateTime converter? This doesn't convert anything, it's a simple call to `Convert.ToDateTime(text)`. This will use the current locale's format

Comment: Code in `CsvDateTimeConverter` seems to work correctly (if I call it directly). Maybe it is a problem with the registration of the converter? See [C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ypQ5Nt)

Comment: This is the US format. You don't need a custom converter for this. Have you tried setting the Culture through `Configuration.CultureInfo` ?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Have you tried to read using CsvDateTimeConverte

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider only if you use a US locale on your machine. The format string isn't used anywhere. It's just a call to `Convert.ToDateTime(text)`.

Comment: @ash which version of CsvHelper are you using? The code has been changing a lot lately, with breaking changes from one RC version to the next. Setting [Configuration.CultureInfo](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/Configuration.cs#L350) *should* work, eg `myHelper.Configuration.CultureInfo= CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos am using 2.16.3 version

Comment: What happens when you debug? Does the converter get a reasonable looking string sent into it? Does it not break in your method at all? Does something else happen? Some basic debugging should be the first step before you ask a question here. And if you've done the basic debugging you should share the results of that with us.

Comment: @Chris look at the code. There's no point in debugging. It's only a call to `Convert.ToDateTime()` without a format string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The code is very simple but `Convert.ToDateTime` will never return null so either it is throwing an exception (which I would expect to be noticeable) or it is not running that code. This could mean it is not getting to the method at all or that it is getting in but `text` is null when it gets there. Debugging will definitely be helpful in narrowing down exactly what the bug is in my opinion.

Comment: In fact - it occurs to me that the OP says "returns null for the DateTime property" but the `MyDateTime` property is not nullable. So the OP is missing something fundamental out of his question there...

Comment: @Chris that code is [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) itself. And its settings to ignore errors. If you use the wrong culture to read data, you get either an exception or a null, depending on the configuration. There's no need to debug, nor is anything missing

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Ah, ok. I'm still confused about exactly where the null is though... :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried to make a break point on ConvertFromString method but it is not being hit.

Comment: @ash you don't need to use a custom type converter. You can specify the format, culture and a lot more through TypeConverterOption. +1 because I wouldn't have found it either if it wasn't for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to specify a custom type converter. This is the US-style DateTime format, with milliseconds added. All you need is to specify the correct culture and possibly, the format to be used.

One option is to set the `Configuration.CultureInfo` property to the US culture :

```
reader.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

The following code will generate and read US dates *without* milliseconds :

```
        using (var file = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
        {
            var writer = new CsvWriter(file);
            writer.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            writer.WriteRecords(items);
        }

        using (var file = new StreamReader("test.csv"))
        {
            var reader= new CsvReader(file);
            reader.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            var models=reader.GetRecords<MyModel>().ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(models[0]);                
        }
```

You can specify a different format for the field through the `TypeConverterOptions` method in the class map :

```
public sealed class CsvMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<MyModel>
{
    public CsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");
        Map(m => m.ID);
    }
}
```

The following code, which just adds the class map, will generate US dates with milliseconds :

```
        using (var file = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
        {
            var writer = new CsvWriter(file);
            writer.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            writer.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();
            writer.WriteRecords(items);
        }

        using (var file = new StreamReader("test.csv"))
        {
            var reader= new CsvReader(file);
            reader.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
            reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvMap>();                
            var models=reader.GetRecords<MyModel>().ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(models[0]);                
        }

Date,ID
10/12/2017 11:56:11.016,1
10/11/2017 11:56:11.021,2
```

You can specify the CultureInfo as a TypeConverterOption as well, if you don't want to set the culture for the entire file :

```
    public CsvMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff")
                        .TypeConverterOption(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        Map(m => m.ID);
    }
```

**NOTE**

CsvHelper released a major update (3.0) recently (as in this week). It wasn't there last week! The current version is 3.2.0.

In this version, `CsvClassMap` becomes `CsvMap` and the TypeConverterOptions method becomes an object with methods that return a MapMember :

```
    public CsvMap()
    {
        string format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
        var enUS=CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

        Map(m => m.Date).TypeConverterOption.Format(format)
                        .TypeConverterOption.CultureInfo(enUS);
        Map(m => m.ID);
    }
```

There's still  no documentation for [Type Converters](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/type-converters) much less TypeConverterOptions. I found the method from [this Github issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/39) which should serve as documentation.

The other option is to check [the source code](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/tree/master/src/CsvHelper) itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return null;

    return Convert.ToDateTime(text);
}
```

You are probably missing your Special Format here. I am a fan of DateTime.TryConvert(...) - do not like Convert.XXXX myself. Is there a reason to use that one over the Type-specific conversion methods?

Comment: No `Convert.` method accepts a format string. That's provided by the `ParseExact` methods of each type

Answer (score -1):

This method

```
Convert.ToDateTime(text);
```

has an overload that takes in format which you would have to specify here. Try like that.

[image]

**EDIT:**

In your ConvertFromString method add this:

```
public override object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) return null;

    DateTimeFormatInfo info = new DateTimeFormatInfo() { FullDateTimePattern = DateStringFormat };

    return Convert.ToDateTime(text, info);
}
```

Comment: Look carefully at the image. That's for a `CultureInfo`, not a format string

Comment: Wouldn't you define the DatePattern in the DateTimeFormatInfo and wouldn't that be used by the given method?

Comment: @Rob: You might think that but the line `private const string DateStringFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";` in the question clearly disagrees with you. And in general I am not sure why you would either create or find a `CultureInfo` when all you want is a date format. Having the date format there clearly (as in this example) means there is no question about what the format should be - no need to look up a culture to find out what format they use, etc.

Comment: I am not saying you have to look up a culture. Just make a new DateTimeFormatInfo and give the property FullDateTimePattern the format OP specified. Thats it! You can define a date like this - 12WhatsUp10WhatsUp2017 and make a DateTimeFormatInfo that would define FullDateTimePattern as "ddMMyyy" and in DateSeparator you can put in WhatsUp and your Convert.ToDateTime method would convert it. Try it out! He is only interested in FullDateTimePattern anyway.

Comment: @Rob there's a reason people use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`.